# How to trigger Google Analytics from code?

Tags: .net, javascript, google-analytics

My app reads an (html) file from my website, and I would like to track accesses to that file using Google Analytics. As the GA Javascript does not get executed when reading the file, it is not tracked. Is there a way to trigger GA directly from code or alternatively, to execute the Javascript from a .NET app without adding a bunch of dependencies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Analytics works by making a webrequest through javascript back to Google's server.  If you want to do this programmatically, you just have to make this web request yourself.  I would use Fiddler or FireBug to capture what the request looks like when you load the page in your browser.  Then you can use that same URL in your .Net app.

Comment: Thanks David. Looking at the URL, and the Urchin javascript code, it doesn't seem that straightforward. There are a lot of 'magic' numbers in the URL that I cannot explain, and that change between requests. Nevertheless I'll try to add this to my app and see what happens.

Comment: GA provides a public API for that, you really don't have to track down the requests.

Comment: It has to have those magic numbers, otherwise anyone can change/impact  visitor statistics (and other things) of anyone else's website. :)

Comment: You may find modifying something like this http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/ useful.  Its server-side tracking for instances (in this case, mobile devices) that may not support javascript. You could create a HTTPHandler for the the app serving the html file, and turn the recommendations in the link to a service call. If you do that, you may find it easier to create another account just for those requests, as all of you traffic would likely be reported from your hosting server. it may be easier to actually do it in a standard way and host the html in a browser within your app.

Comment: Here is a list of the tracking code parameters http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingTroubleshooting.html#gifParameters

Answer (score 5):

I have recently released a .net library that allows you to natively log a page view with Google Analytics through code. It is released as open source under GNU so all that is required is proper attribution.

You can get the library here: http://www.diaryofaninja.com/projects/details/ga-dot-net

example usage of the API:

```
GooglePageView pageView = new GooglePageView("My page title",
                                "www.mydomain.com",
                                "/my-page-url.html");
TrackingRequest request = new RequestFactory().BuildRequest(pageView);
GoogleTracking.FireTrackingEvent(request);
```

There is also a built in HTTP Handler that allows you to fire tracking events by simply including a tracking pixel on the page:

```
<img src="/tracker.asmx?domain=mydomain.com&pagetitle=My%20Page%20Title&url=/my-page.aspx" />
```

Alternatively you can use jquery to track links within a page using Google Analytics (zip, jpg, etc) - blogged about it a while ago here:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2009/09/17/random-file-zip-and-pdf-tracking-using-jquery-amp-google-analytics

Comment: If i would like to set the Google Analytics Code on the fly (instead of statically in web.config) can I just set request.AnalyticsAccountCode dynamically before calling GoogleTracking.FireTrackingEvent(request)?

Answer (score 3):

```
private void analyticsmethod4(string trackingId, string pagename)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    long timestampFirstRun, timestampLastRun, timestampCurrentRun, numberOfRuns;

    // Get the first run time
    timestampFirstRun = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    timestampLastRun = DateTime.Now.Ticks-5;
    timestampCurrentRun = 45;
    numberOfRuns = 2;

    // Some values we need
    string domainHash = "123456789"; // This can be calcualted for your domain online
    int uniqueVisitorId = rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999); // Random
    string source = "Shop";
    string medium = "medium123";
    string sessionNumber = "1";
    string campaignNumber = "1";
    string culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    string screenRes = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width + "x" + Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;


    string statsRequest = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif" +
        "?utmwv=4.6.5" +
        "&utmn=" + rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999) +
    //  "&utmhn=hostname.mydomain.com" +
        "&utmcs=-" +
        "&utmsr=" + screenRes +
        "&utmsc=-" +
        "&utmul=" + culture +
        "&utmje=-" +
        "&utmfl=-" +
        "&utmdt=" + pagename +
        "&utmhid=1943799692" +
        "&utmr=0" +
        "&utmp=" + pagename +
        "&utmac=" +trackingId+ // Account number
        "&utmcc=" +
            "__utma%3D" + domainHash + "." + uniqueVisitorId + "." + timestampFirstRun + "." + timestampLastRun + "." + timestampCurrentRun + "." + numberOfRuns +
            "%3B%2B__utmz%3D" + domainHash + "." + timestampCurrentRun + "." + sessionNumber + "." + campaignNumber + ".utmcsr%3D" + source + "%7Cutmccn%3D(" + medium + ")%7Cutmcmd%3D" + medium + "%7Cutmcct%3D%2Fd31AaOM%3B";


    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadData(statsRequest);
        //Stream data = client.OpenRead(statsRequest);
        //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
        //string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

}
```

refer this - http://tilr.blogspot.com/2012/10/google-analytics-use-google-analytics.html

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics provides two way to track custom actions, events, or whatever you deal with. In your case, the trivial solution is to generate a virtual pageview for the HTML file your application reads in. Call the appropriate [JavaScript function](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55521):

```
pageTracker._trackPageview("/Foo.html");
```

This way every time *Foo.html* is processed, a pageview will be generated for it as same as it would be a normal query to your application.

If you'd like to distinguish these *Foo.html*s from the normal pageviews, GA has a nice feature called [Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerOverview.html) then you should take a look at.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the WebBrowser component to load the .html file, and thereby trigger the GA tracker. The WebBrowser component executes the embedded JavaScript.

```
using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
{
    wb.Url = new Uri(@"mytrackingpage.html");
    while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Now all I have to do is to add some errorhandling, get rid of the ugly DoEvents and move the WebBrowser to a separate thread.

Comment: Curious to know what your final code looks like, after doing all of the "now all I have to do is ..." stuff. =)

Answer (score 0):

Google has libraries (in alpha) for several different languages for accessing various google APIs, including Analytics -- there's a nice description here -- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ and the .NET library is https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/analytics/v3

Also keep in mind their privacy policy you have to adhere to when using this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy