# Google analytics for a page not loaded in browsers

Tags: google-analytics

I have an aspx page (without javascript) which is called by different systems (in other words custom component written in dot net and php). I want to enable google analytics for this aspx page. Is there a way to enable google analytics on a page which is not loaded in a browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846460/cause-google-analytics-log-from-non-web-application-eg-via-webclient something like this maybe?

Comment: The newest Version of Google Analytics comes with a language agnostic, rest-like interface that can be implemented serverside: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

Comment: thanks for the responses, while trying to using the http://www.google-analytics.com/collect to submit the data from my server...i get the following message
Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 173.194.112.94:443
Does that mean i need to ask my server team to allow this IP from the firewall?

Comment: found the problem, this was due to the firewall stopping it..i used a proxy before firing the POST