# Is there any analytic tool can apply server side on gae?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-analytics

I have an app running on GAE which has no **webpages**(actually, a 302 redirection is performed), so i can only do the analytic on server side.

So I wonder if there's some tools can handle the request and do the analytics.

And I see that most url-shorten services can do the analytic(like goo.gl), were they doing this on server side? i see they're also doing server side redirections(http 301)

by the way, i use `python`, if that effects

Comment: You should be able to create request to google analytics's like here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804309/how-to-trigger-google-analytics-from-code

Comment: Quick google lead me to this link http://www.atlantaanalytics.com/practicing-web-analytics/how-does-google-analytics-handle-301-and-302-redirects/. Cheers

Comment: @SathishJayapal the link is all about how ga handles requests from 301 or 302, not what i am concerned.

Comment: Have you looked at prodeagle.com for your purposes?

Comment: @Bert yeah, but not convenient enough, i chose to perform a client-side redirection finally

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to analyse, and how you want to display the data. Is it number of hits, load, latency?

One easy to implement option, which will probably handle some of your requirements, is http://www.prodeagle.com. It does all the graphing for you. All you need to do is provide the data for your counters on their system and it does the rest. If you need country and city analytics, you could probably create some counters that use city and country from the request header. Take a look at their site and see if it suits your needs.